# Cakephp get childrens associated data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

- I have a product that has a brand. A brand_id in product table.
- A brand has a collection of images.
- Images have the id, product_id and path in the table.

When in the product index, you get the entity that has the associated brands data from like below. You can't go any deeper to what i want than this:

```
    $product->brands[0]['image_id'];
```

To get the path, I want to be able to go something like:

```
    $product->brand->image['path'];
```

Currently the product index gets its stuff like this:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Brands']
    ];
    $products = $this->paginate($this->Products);

    $this->set(compact('products'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['products']);
```

So how do i approach a 'subquery' or something to also get the image table data (secondary association of product, through brands)

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

To get deeper associations, modify your query options:

```
'contain' => [
    'Brands' => ['Images']
]
```

Comment: Further reading: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain**